# Choosing a database for cartesian coordinates

Tags: database, hibernate, relational-database, spatial, hibernate-spatial

I'm trying to figure out, which database would be the best choice to store cartesian coordinates (x,y,z).

I want to query for

- the distance between 2 positions,
- which positions are in a sphere arround a given position,
- which connections between 2 positions intersect with a sphere around a given position.

The database should also be able to handle transactions.

I have no exerience in any other database then mysql, which doesn't seem to be an option, so I'm open to any suggestion. It'll be something new to me anyway.

Which database driver would fit best? Plain JDBC, hibernate, hibernate-spatial (which had the last update in 2011?), or something I haven't had in my mind yet.

Thank you in advance for reading and sharing your views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)** database and its **[Postgis](http://www.postgis.net/)** extension. The openstreetmaps.org project for example works with them. So you could somehow say it's a proven technology.

In our current project we are using plain JDBC and hibernate (+hibernate-spatial) together to acces the geo-database.  Untill now we cant't complain at all.

*BTW:  Hibernate spatial will and be part of Hibernate 5*